# Увеличить корневой раздел Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, сервер

столкнулся с проблемой, при установке Ubuntu Server система выделила всего лишь 100гб для раздела. Сам диск 500гб. Хотел бы увеличить данный раздел. Cам раздел 169гб но в файловом менеджере указано, что выделено только 100гб, как увеличить "выделяемый объем"?

[image: список разделов]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Lunix Server 20 LTCS интерфейс через эмуляцию,требуется увеличить размер раздела, сам раздел 169гб но в файловом менеджере указано, что выделено только 100гб, как увеличить "выделяемый объем"?

Comment: Тебе наверное нужно чё-то типа такого: https://www.dmosk.ru/instruktions.php?object=lvm&ysclid=l9hmd7pnvi750420514#resizeup