# Как увеличить том Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gparted

Lunix Server 20 LTCS интерфейс через эмуляцию,требуется увеличить размер раздела, сам раздел 169гб но в файловом менеджере указано, что выделено только 100гб, как увеличить "выделяемый объем"? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Увеличить корневой раздел Ubuntu Server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1458740/%d0%a3%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb-ubuntu-server)

Comment: не надо задавать вопрос два раза, можно добавить нужную информацию в предыдущий вопрос

Answer (score 0):

У вас на разделе pv,  поверх pv натянут ch, внутри которого lv, а уже на нем fs.

Чтоб растянуть раздел нужно сначала растянуть lv.

```
lvextend -L +68G /dev/mapper/имя_лв
```

А потом растянуть раздел

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/имя_лв
```

Чтоб растянуть дальше нужно добавить pv в vg,  а дальше растягивать lv и фс